# Is it possible to include fields in a sharepoint list directly from elements.xml file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to provision a SharePoint 2013 tasks list from a spfx app using the feature framework.  I am able to create an out of the box tasks list with the following list definition in my elements.xml file.

```
<ListInstance
  FeatureId="f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0"
  Title="Tasks" 
  Description="Task List created using SharePoint Framework"
  TemplateType="171"
  Url="Lists/Tasks">
</ListInstance>
```

This works as expected to create the new task list with the timeline and checkboxes, etc.  The problem is I want to add two custom fields to this list.  The normal way to do this is with a custom schema.xml, but using a typical custom list schema doesn't work with a Tasks list.  I tried to find the custom schema for the TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy feature on my SharePoint 2013 server but I could only find the schema.xml for the older 2010 tasks. So I am wondering if there is any way I can add fields to this list without a custom schema.xml.  I don't care about adding the fields to views, they just need to be added to the list.